# strange behavior of -webkit-appearance: none; in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

I have some weird behavior from chrome, when the focus is on a input or select element, when this element have  -webkit-appearance: none;.

As sone as i click on the element and the element comes into focus it changes size. and stays like that. I can't seem to find the problem. But it's apperent that is the  -webkit-appearance: none; because when i remove it it works perfectly.

This behavior only shows in windows on chrome as far as i can tell.

the behavior can be watch here: 
http://development.nmdesigns.dk/webshop/index.php/webshop/category/35-men

When clicking on the slecect list on top or the buttons.
they become samller then they where.

Comment: please provide your snippet here. If your provided link breaks, then this question is rendered **useless** to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The problem was switching between fonts when the select became i focus.
So a font-family: inherit;

did fix it.